# Mini cart in header using divi is not getting updated on changing the cart items count:

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, ajax

I am having a wordpress site which is using the Divi theme. When I update the number of items in the cart, the mini cart on the header is not getting updated accordignly. However, the number of items in the mini cart are getting updated on re-loading the page.

Divi is using the below function for updating the cart,

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'et_show_cart_total' ) ) { 
       function et_show_cart_total( $args = array() ) { 
               if ( ! class_exists( 'woocommerce' ) || ! WC()->cart ) { 
                       return; 
               } 

               $defaults = array( 
                       'no_text' => false, 
               ); 

               $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults ); 

               $items_number = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(); 

               $url = function_exists( 'wc_get_cart_url' ) ? wc_get_cart_url() : WC()->cart->get_cart_url(); 

               printf( 
                       '<a href="%1$s" class="et-cart-info"> 
                               <span>%2$s</span> 
                       </a>', 
                       esc_url( $url ), 
                       ( ! $args['no_text'] 
                               ? esc_html( sprintf( 
                                       _nx( '%1$s Item', '%1$s Items', $items_number, 'WooCommerce items number', 'Divi' ), 
                                       number_format_i18n( $items_number ) 
                               ) ) 
                               : '' 
                       ) 
               ); 
       } 
}
```

How can I update the mini cart on updating the number of items in the cart on ajax call?

Please can anyone help?

Comment: Did you added `global $woocmmerce` ?

Comment: Try as DHL17 is suggesting.

Comment: Thanks but I kind of fixed my issue as per my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding the below in my functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'your_custom_functions', 10, 1 ); 

function your_custom_functions( $fragments ) {
    $fragments['.your_cart_class'] = '' . WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() . ' Items';
    return $fragments; 
}
```

Comment: It's important to note if your theme requires html, you may want to return that as well. For example, using Divi I actually had to make a copy of their show_cart_total function, return the formatted html string (sprintf) and then set the desired fragment to that. This article has some more info: https://iconicwp.com/blog/update-custom-cart-count-html-ajax-add-cart-woocommerce/